# how to display alert message in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2

I am using one controller which is inserting values in the database. I want to display alert message from controller when the values insertesd in the database successfully.
Is it possible. If yes then how?

Comment: what do you mean by alert? as in javascript browser alert('helo world'); type of alert?

Comment: yes, like alert('Successfully Inserted");

Comment: can you post your current code on controller ?And  how do you post data to controller  ? Is it using jquery post?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically that depends on how are you inserting the value into the database, as you would need a method to tells you whether the insertion was successful. As there's a few ways to do that now, linq/entity framework/sql/etc.

Then after you know whether did the insertion happens, then you can just assign a value to a variable and then from the code/aspx just check the value and do a simple alert.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//i'm using jquery ready event which will call the javascript chunk after the page has completed loading
$(document).ready(function(){
//assuming that your variable name from the code behind is bInsertSuccess
var bSuccess = "<%= bInsertSuccess %>";
if(bSuccess){
    alert("Successfully Inserted");
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer; I liked it because it is a very clean and very straight forward way of doing it; it also gave me the idea on how to handle it on the .NET Core MVC world. All I had to do was adding a property to the ViewModel used in the View, this property was set in the view controller action with the result of the save operation, in my case MessageId. Then in the JavaScript code in this answer I changed the if block to if(@Model.MessageId > 0) { alert("Message successfully sent!"); } else if (@Model.MessageId == -1) { alert("Failed to send message. Please try again later."); }

Answer (score 19):

You can add the result to ViewData. For example:

```
if (SaveToDbOK)
{
    ViewData["Success"] = "Data was saved successfully.";
   // Do other things or return view
}
```

In your view you can place anywhere:

MVC2:

```
<% if (ViewData["Success"] != null) { %>
    <div id="successMessage">
        <%: ViewData["Success"] %>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

MVC3:

```
@if (ViewData["Success"] != null) {
    <div id="successMessage">
        @ViewData["Success"]
    </div>
@}
```

I used this approach in my last project in order to make the information returned from the server unobtrusive. Checking whether ViewData["Success"] or ViewData["Failure"] are done in the Master page, the divs are formatted using CSS, jQuery code was used to hide the notifications after 5 seconds.

Regards,

Huske

Answer (score 5):

```
public ActionResult UploadPropertyImage()
{
    // Business logic....
    return Content("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Save Successfully');</script>");
}
```

Comment: By adding js in to the content of the view from the controller you break encapsulation, the view should be ready to receive the alert. melaos' answer respects encapsulation.

Comment: But that's more of a personal preference, I mean yes you should follow the design pattern but in some cases it just over-complicates an otherwise trivial task. In my case for example I only need to do this in one place, and we don't use JavaScript in our views, and so for my case this solution is exactly what I want, a quick way to just send back an alert.

Answer (score 0):

You may add below code to tell user

```
Return Content("Data added successfully");
```